# Time complexity of double invarient for loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have an array of lists(i.e. each cell in the array contains a list). The length of the array is `n` and the sum of all the lengths of all the lists is `k`

I want to iterate over all the list elements(in the whole array):

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < array[i].list.Length(); ++j) {
        //do something in O(1)
    }
}
```

**NOTE** the inner loop runs less than `k` times per an iteration of the outer loop, but the total iterations it does for all the `i` is `k`

**Question**Does the time complexity of the code is O(n + k)? Or would it be O(n*k)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question** Does the time complexity of the code is O(n + k)? Or would it be O(n*k)?

<s>Neither.</s>

The complexity is `O(n + k)`. In the case where `n <= k`, this would equal `O(k)`, but this is not necessarily the case.

#### `n <= k` (original answer)

If the sum of all lengths is `k`, then, if you don't do anything else in the outer loop, the running time would be `O(k)`. `n` is irrelevant in this case, since there is nothing interesting you're doing `n` times. Your data just happens to be split up in `n` chunks.

On average, each list's size would be `k/n`. That makes the time complexity of the algorithm `O(n * k/n)` which results in `O(k)`.

#### `n > k`

In the case that `n` is larger than `k`, `n` becomes relevant since work has to be done each time, even if it's only checking the `Length()` of `array[i]`. Because of that, in this case the complexity is `O(n + k)`.

#### Update

As [Jordi Vermeulen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2188136/jordi-vermeulen) correctly points out in the comments, my original answer that only took into consideration the case where `n <= k` is <s>incomplete</s> incorrect. The answer has been edited accordingly.

Comment: interesting..could you provide a mathematical formula maybe? i though: `k1+k2+..+kn = k = O(k)` will that do it?

Comment: Another question, if i performed in the outer loop O(1) instructions besides the inner loop, it will be then a total of O(n+k), right?

Comment: This is not true when n is asymptotically larger than k. Your argument about the average complexity of an iteration being k / n also does not hold when many of the positions in the array are empty (you still do O(1) work for each of those).

Comment: @JordiVermeulen You're right, I didn't consider that. =] Will edit.

Answer (score 2):

This is O(n + k), which is O(k) when n is O(k). This is, however, not necessarily the case (as suggested in the answer by Bart van Nierop). Consider, for instance, the case where n = k<sup>2</sup>. The loop is still running k<sup>2</sup> times, so you can't say the complexity is O(k), even though in many iterations no work will be done other than increasing the counter.

Answer (score 0):

You should use n*k.

> Foreach cols, process each lines.

You've got to do a loop (for or foreach) over each columns (n).
And then inside the n loop, you do another loop (for or foreach) that process each rows (k).

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < array[i].list.length(); j++) {
     // do something with array[i][j]
   }
}
```

Comment: could you explain more? since the **total** running time of the inner loop is O(k) regardless of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

For every `i` of the external loop, the inner loop is run `array[i].list.Length()` which you say is `k`:

```
k times + -+
k times +  |
...        |
...        +--- n times
...        |
k times   -+
```

So the resulting time is O(n * k)

Comment: `array[i].list.Length()` is less than `k`, but the sum of `array[i].list.Length()` for every `i` is `k`. Means that the inner loop doesn't run `k` times on each iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score -1):

O(k).do something part will occur k times.
n is irrelevant in this case.